# Using Model Query in Laravel: Schedule

Tags: mysql, laravel, schedule

I wanted to create dynamic scheduling jobs so I have used model in Kernel.php like below

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $tasks = \App\Model\Task::where('enabled', true)->get();
}
```

It works on local, but when deploying to production it throws the following error:

```
>> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

> @php artisan package:discover

In Connection.php line 664:

could not find driver (SQL: select * from `tasks` where `enabled` = 1) `
```

If I remove the model query from `kernel.php` and define static schedule it works fine as expected. But I need to query database in Schedule to setup it dynamic.

I have checked the production `php.ini` and found that `pdo_mysql` is enabled.

Can any one guide me what is missing in production environment?

Comment: Try running `php -m` in your production shell and see if the module is actually loaded.

Comment: Yes,  it is loaded.

Comment: Here is complete list. 
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: what does your .env file say for DB_CONNECTION and whats the value of "driver" inside config/database.php for that specific connection ?

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: yes, the solution is given below..

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` settings in production, do you have defined `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` ?

Also `App\Console\Kernel.php` is not very good place to query something.

try to extract that logic to own command, with command `php artisan make:command TaskCommand` you can simply create own command and then you just schedule it

```
$schedule->command('signature_from:task_comand')->dailyAt('9:00');
```

There is very good documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#writing-commands)

Comment: Yes, I have defined it in .env and I can query models everywhere except in Kernal.php. 
I just want to manage the crons through database and registering jobs as below: - 
`$schedule->job(new $class, $task->queue)->withoutOverlapping()->cron($interval)->runInBackground();`

But I am not able to get $task records as it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have done more research and found that the issue was only occurring when building with docker. I have added pdo pdo_mysql in config.yml and required database environment variables and now it is working.

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/62#issuecomment-70306737

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $tasks = DB::table('tasks')->where('enabled', true)->get();
}
```